# How to get rows from two nearly identical tables when only a corresponding row is missing or some of the field values are missing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two sql server tables named, Actual_Schedule and Employee_Updated_Schedule. Both have identical columns such as ID, ClockInDate, ClockInTime, ClockOutDate, ClockOutTime, EmployeeName and JobName. The Actual_Schedule has a row corresponding to the assigned schedule created by the manager. An employee has to use the website to clockin and clockout every day. At the end of the day the manager will display the data in an asp.net gridview to compare the rows.

Typically the rows from both the tables should be identical. However some employees may clockin but forget to clockout. In that case the ClockOutDate and ClockOutTime will be missing from the Employee_Updated_Schedule table. Sometimes the employee may forget to clockin, in that case the entire row will be missing. In both cases the manager will fill in using a grid. I have to write a sql to get rows from both the tables, only when either any of the field is missing or the entire row is missing and show in the grid. I thought of writing a query using UNION to get data from these two table. But I don't know how to restrict to retrieve rows only when the row is absent in one table or some of the fields are missing in one table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they join on ID (if they don't then just join on the column they relate with), you can just use a full outer join where the columns are different or the id that can be missing is null. Here is an example.

```
declare @Actual_Schedule table (
ID int
,ClockInDate date
,ClockInTime time
,ClockOutDate date
,ClockOutTime time
)

declare @Employee_Updated_Schedule table (
ID int
,ClockInDate date
,ClockInTime time
,ClockOutDate date
,ClockOutTime time
)

insert @Actual_Schedule (ID, ClockInDate, ClockInTime, ClockOutDate, ClockOutTime)
values (1, '2017-01-03', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(2, '2017-01-04', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(3, '2017-01-05', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(4, '2017-01-06', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(5, '2017-01-07', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')

insert @Employee_Updated_Schedule (ID, ClockInDate, ClockInTime, ClockOutDate, ClockOutTime)
values (1, '2017-01-03', '06:05:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(2, '2017-01-04', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(4, '2017-01-06', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '15:00:00')
,(5, '2017-01-07', '06:00:00', '2017-01-03', '14:57:00') 

select *
from @Actual_Schedule a
full outer join @Employee_Updated_Schedule b on
    a.ID = b.ID
where
    a.ClockInDate <> b.ClockInDate
    or a.ClockInTime <> b.ClockInTime
    or a.ClockOutDate <> b.ClockOutDate
    or a.ClockOutTime <> b.ClockOutTime
    or b.id is null
```

Comment: I think this is better than where I was going on this.